# How to get the element id of the html page displayed

Tags: javascript, android

I have a web view and a button at the bottom . After loading the html page into the web view, when I click on the button I need to get the id of the current focused html element id from the html page. How to get that..?? Help me friends,current focused element in the sense may be the first topic element of the page displayed.

Comment: say what again I dare ya say what again

Comment: Please can you explain more clearly; Android like other HTML5 capable devices support jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap likes.. just use jQuery uTouch

Answer (score 1):

Try this code on button click.This will display the focused element's id in alert box.

```
function showFocusedElemntId(){
  var length_of_total_elm = document.formName.elements.length;
  var elm = document.formName.elements;

  for(var k=0;k<length_of_total_elm;k++){
        if(!elm[k].activeElement && elm[k].activeElement == document.body){
           alert("Focused element's ID is (body element)"+elm[k].id);
           break;
        }     
        else if(elm[k].activeElement){ 
           alert("Focused element's ID is "+elm[k].id);
       }
 }
```

}

Comment: Exactly.So that this will travel for all the elements in the page and find the focused element (which may be button itself ! as you have given the focus to it by clicking on it !) and alerts the id of respective element.

Comment: should i add ur code in the html page or the jave code...i know sounds stupid but pls dont mind

Comment: in HTML between `<script>...</script>` tags.